# Random slope in a model without random intercept

Tags: random-effects-model, glmm

I am looking for a model to fit longitudinal data and opted for GLMM with a logit link.
I tried to add random effects but when both a random slope and random intercept are in the model, this does not converge.
Then I tried to include only one of them and both models converged but I am wondering if I can have a model with random slope without a random intercept. Does this conflicts with the hierarchy of the model? Or, since all subject start at the same point in my data (it's about roses and at day 0, they are all fresh), is it allowed?

The AIC value does drop when the random effect is a random intercept only but I am not sure if I can compare the AIC values.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you using 'lme()' or 'lmer()'? (or something else?) A trick that sometimes works in order to get (slow) convergence out of 'lme()' would be to make it do more EM iterations before moving on to the gradient solver. That being said, if you believe no intercept changes are relevant you shouldn't have them. (And it seems this to be the case in the experiment you describe).

Comment: Actually I am working with SAS (proc nlmixed). R does seem to be attractive to work with for this kind of data, I will take a look at it.
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know that the intercept will always be 0 (or at least will not have any variation). Thus, there's no obvious reason to include an error term for the intercept. The only reason I can think that this would not be the case is if you've centered your time variable, thus changing the location of the 0 point (i.e. the intercept).

It's OK to have a random slope in a model with a fixed intercept.

Comment: It indeed seems to me that the intercept will be 0. I have not centered the time variable so I will probably use the model with random slope only.
Thank you for your answer!